# How to redirect a URL by only changing the domain name, while keeping other URL parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, migration, forwarding

I'm now migrating my website to a new host and domain, and I want to know if I can redirect anyone who enters any URL of the old website to the new website, while keeping all of the URL parameters. for example:
When somebody types in this url `http://www.domainA.com/blog/?p=667`, I want him to be redirected to `http://www.domainB.com/blog/?p=667`.

Is there any way I can do that by adding some .htaccess configurations?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainB.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will preserve your URI while redirecting from domainA to domainB.

Comment: how do you do this without the old domain being preserved in the url?

Comment: This is not preserving old domain. It is going from `domainA` to `domainB`