# problems redirecting sections to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Same question as [How to redirect a URL by only changing the domain name, while keeping other URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956844/how-to-redirect-a-url-by-only-changing-the-domain-name-while-keeping-other-url/37377733#37377733)

but as I have commented in the answers (I realized it´s from 2011 so I decided to ask again):

I follow the rewrite rule and only works for me without anything after the domainA name. If I have any subsection like domainA.com/team/ or domainA.com/contact/ the rewrite rule doesn´t work and stay in the domainA.com site instead of redirecting me to domainB.com/team/ or /contact/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a Wordpress rule above, I changed the order of rules, putting the redirecting rule before the Wordpress rule:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Cpanel for any reason was adding the redirect rule *after* the Wordpress rule, instead of before.